# How to automaticly burn erc-20 tokens after 1 month

Tags: remix, erc-20, ether, function, burn

Im working on a code to automaticly burn tokens after 1 month, is this even possible and if so how can i do this?

Kind regards,
Murk

Comment: One option is to store in the contract the date it will stop being valid. Then any interaction with the token after that date will burn it.

Answer (score 1):

To do anything truly automatically, you will have to use a 3rd party like Chainlink.

You need to look into a Chainlink Keeper.
You will need to have a keeperOnlyBurn function that will be called by the keeper (and the keeper only) once a month and will burn a certain number of token.

Look for the chainlink docs, they have everything you need to set it up.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I look into that!